# Assign exception handler to methods of class

Tags: python, exception

I have a class with multiple functions. These functions will handle similar kinds of exceptions. Can I have a handler function and assign this to the functions.

At the end, I would want that there should be no exception handling in functions but on exception the control should go to this handler function.

```
Class Foo:
  def a():
    try:
      some_code
    except Exception1 as ex:
      log error
      mark file for error
      other housekeeping
      return some_status, ex.error
    except Exception2 as ex:
      log error
      mark file for error
      other housekeeping
      return some_status, ex.error
```

Similarly, other functions would have the same kind of exceptions. I wanted to have all these exception handling in a separate method. Just that the functions should hand over the control to exception handler function.

I can think of calling every function from the wrapper handler function. But that looked very weird to me.

```
Class Foo:
  def process_func(func, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
      func(*args, **kwargs)
    except Exception1 as ex:
      log error
      mark file for error
      other housekeeping
      return some_status, ex.error
    except Exception2 as ex:
      log error
      mark file for error
      other housekeeping
      return some_status, ex.error

  def a(*args, **kwargs):
    some_code
```

Is there a better way for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can define a function decorator:

```
def process_func(func):
    def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except ...
    return wrapped_func
```

And use as:

```
@process_func
def func(...):
   ...
```

So that `func(...)` is equivalent to `process_func(func)(...)`, and errors are handled inside `wrapped_func`.